# MVVM array does not update in xaml View

Tags: arrays, xaml, mvvm, binding, maui-community-toolkit

MVVM newbie here.  When I try to bind an array, ChoiceText[], in MVVM, the initial values show in my View, but the updated values do not.

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int _questionNumber = 0;
    private int _numberOfQuestions = 30;
    MainPage.quizQuestion _question = new MainPage.quizQuestion();

    [ObservableProperty]
    string _answerText = "no answer yet...";

    [ObservableProperty]
    string _questionText = "what's this a picture of?";

    [ObservableProperty]
    string _imagePath = "pic1_72dpi.jpg";

    [ObservableProperty]
    string[] _choiceText = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

    private void LoadQuestion()
    {
        _question = LoadHardCodedQuestion(_questionNumber);
        QuestionText = _question.QText;
        AnswerText = string.Empty;
        ImagePath = _question.imagePath;
        for (int i = 0; i < _question.choices.Length; i++) { ChoiceText[i] = _question.choices[i]; }
    }
}
```

In my .xaml View code-behind:

```xml
<Image Grid.Row="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
               BackgroundColor="Black"/>

<Label x:Name ="lblQuestion"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Text="{Binding QuestionText}"
               FontSize="18"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

<Button Text="{Binding ChoiceText[0]}" 
                Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Style="{StaticResource defaultButtonStyle}"
                Command="{Binding SubmitAnswerCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
<Button Text="{Binding ChoiceText[1]}" 
                Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Style="{StaticResource defaultButtonStyle}" 
                Command="{Binding SubmitAnswerCommand}" CommandParameter="2"/>
<Button Text="{Binding ChoiceText[2]}" 
                Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Style="{StaticResource defaultButtonStyle}"
                Command="{Binding SubmitAnswerCommand}" CommandParameter="3"/>
<Button Text="{Binding ChoiceText[3]}" 
                Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Style="{StaticResource defaultButtonStyle}" 
                Command="{Binding SubmitAnswerCommand}" CommandParameter="4"/>

<Label x:Name ="lblAnswer" IsVisible="True"
               Grid.Row="6"
               Text="{Binding AnswerText}"
               FontSize="18"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
```

The other Observable Properties update in the View without issue.

I could define ChoiceText[] as 4 unique variables, ChoiceText1, ChoiceText2, etc., but I'd like to be able to bind this array and potentially larger ones.  Have I not bound this correctly?

Thank you!
abedaun

Comment: You have made the property observable, but the array elements themselves are not. You need to use an observable array type (`ObservableArray<T>` iirc), binding to the array elements will not have any sort of change notification mechanism

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0 ah my memory fails me, it's `ObservableCollection` I believe you want

Comment: You can also assign a new array like `ChoiceText = _question.choices;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback!

I couldn't find anything in the community toolkit for ObservableArray, but ObservableCollection does look like it would work, though a little differently.

Sir Rufo's answer worked perfectly for me though -- instead of looping over each element of the array, if I assign ChoiceText = _question.choices; the _choiceText observable property gets updated and *so do each of the array elements*.  Perfect, thank you Sir Rufo!

Abedaun

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).